# How to register a face in face recognition?

Tags: panasonic

I want to use the face recognition feature on my Panasonic GH3. When I tap to turn it on in the menu, it says Please register a face. There is no one else here at the moment to test it on. Do I simply take a close up of any face? But then what? Where does the registering come in?

Comment: It should work with a magazine for testing purposes.

Comment: It needs multiple poses of the person, so a magazine might not work, but give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the manual](http://service.us.panasonic.com/OPERMANPDF/DMCGH3_ADV.PDF), pp. 173-174 show the registration process. You basically need to make a headshot, with the subject facing the camera. You can use up to three shots for each person. The registration is probably used to a) tag the photo with a person's name, and b) during face-detection AF to refine the recognition and avoid latching onto [the wrong thing](http://www.oddee.com/item_98248.aspx).

Comment: inkista--Thank you. Now I understand why I was confused. I really wanted to activate the face DETECTION feature, which I've found in the manual.